# Método buscar para una Lista Doblemente Enlazada en c++?

Tags: c++

Intenté implementar un método "Buscar" en una lista doblemente enlazada pero no me funciona. No sé si estoy recorriendo bien la lista o solo no encuentra coincidencias por algún error de lógica. Este método tiene como finalidad encontrar los datos que le pasemos como parámetros a la función. El objetivo es que la función tenga como parámetro la palabra el valor que quiero buscar, y me tiene que retornar verdadero (porque es un booleano). Si alguien tiene una idea de como hacerlo me serviría bastante la verdad, gracias.

```
template<typename G>
class Node
{
public:
   G data;
   Node<G>*sig;
   Node<G>*ant;
   Node(G data):data(data),sig(nullptr),ant(nullptr){}
};

template<typename G>

class ListaDoblementeEnlazada {
    Node<G>* ini;
    Node<G>* fin;
    size_t t;
public:
    ListaDoblementeEnlazada() {
        ini = fin = nullptr;
        t = 0;
    }

    Node<G>* mostrar_ini() { return ini; }

    void push_front(G data) {
        Node<G>* n = new Node<G>(data);
        if (t == 0) {
            ini = n;
            fin = n;
        }
        else {
            n->sig;
            ini = n;
        }
        ++t;
    }
    void mostrar(function<void (G)>f) {
        Node<G>* aux = ini;
        while (aux->sig!=nullptr)
        {
            f(aux->data);
            aux = aux->sig;
        }
        f(aux->data);
        cout << "\n";
    }

    void _imprimir_recursivo(Node<G>* aux, function<void(G)>f) {
        if (aux == fin) {
            f(aux->data);
            return;
        }
        f(aux->data);
        _imprimir_recursivo(aux->sig,f);
    }

    void imprimir_recursivo(function<void(G)>f) {
        _imprimir_recursivo(ini,f);
    }

    G ObtenerInicio() {
        if (ini != nullptr) {
            return ini->data;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    G ObtenerFinal() {
        if (fin != nullptr) {
            return fin->data;
        }
        return 0;
    }

   /* G ObtenerPosicion(int pos) {
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < t)
        {
            if (pos == 0)
                ObtenerInicio();
            else if (pos == t - 1)
                ObtenerFinal();
            else
            {
                Node<G>* aux = ini;
                for (size_t i = 0; i < pos; i++)
                    aux = aux->sig;
                return aux->data;
            }
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }*/

    bool Buscar(G data){
        Node<G>*aux=ini;
        if(t==0){
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            while (aux!=nullptr)
            {
                aux=aux->sig;
            }
            if(aux->data=data){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    void Vacio() {
        if (t == 0)cout << "La lista está vacía." << endl;
        else cout << "La lista tiene valores." << endl;
    }
    
    size_t ReturnTamanio() { return t; }

};
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Sube lo que hayas investigado o intentado. Difícilmente recibas ayuda sino. También lee [tour] y [ask] si aún no lo has hecho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te sucede en la función es, simplemente, que al recorrer la lista no compruebas si alguno de los nodos tiene el valor buscado.

Esta tarea la dejas para el final, cuando ya has recorrido todos los nodos:

```
bool Buscar(G data){
    Node<G>*aux=ini;
    if(t==0){
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        while (aux!=nullptr) // <<--- recorres la lista
        {
            aux=aux->sig;
        }                    // <--- fin del bucle

        if(aux->data=data){ // <<--- y aqui compruebas el valor
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Tienes que meter el `if` dentro del bucle:

```
bool Buscar(G data){
    Node<G>*aux=ini;
    if(t!=0){
    {
        while (aux!=nullptr)
        {
            if(aux->data=data){
                return true;
            }

            aux=aux->sig;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

La función `Buscar` tiene algunos problemas.

- `aux->data=data` no es una comparación. Probablemente hayas querido escribir `aux->data == data` que se evalúa como **true** si los dos operandos son iguales.
- Recorre la lista hasta al final y luego hace la comparación.

Para saber si algún nodo tiene el valor esperado, se debe comparar con cada uno de sus valores.

Arreglando estos problemas obtienes un código así:

```
bool Buscar(G data){
    Node<G> *aux = ini;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < t && aux; i++){
        if (aux->data == data)
            return true;

        aux = aux->sig;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Nota que no verifico si `t == 0` porque ya lo hace el for. También que la verificación `aux == nullptr` se reemplazó por simplemente `aux`. Puedes [ver la documentación sobre este comportamiento](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions).

También quiero mencionar que el nombre `Contiene` describe mejor que `Buscar` lo que hace la función. `Buscar` suena a que vas a devolver el nodo que contenga el valor buscado o quizá su posición.

---

De aquí en adelante haré algunos comentarios sobre tu programa.

- En el **else** de la función `push_front` te faltó `= ini`. Quedando la línea así: `n->sig = ini;`
- Las funciones `ObtenerInicio` y `ObtenerFinal` deben devolver un valor de tipo G pero tu devuelves `0`. El código no compilará si G no es un tipo numérico o no existe una conversión apropiada.

Dos posibles soluciones son construir un objeto del tipo esperado, lo cual fallará si el tipo no tiene un constructor sin parámetros:

```
return G();
```

O devolver un puntero o una referencia al nodo o a la variable correspondiente.

- `_imprimir_recursivo`, como toda función recursiva, tiene el potencial de generar un error del tipo **StackOverflow** (te quedaste sin memoria).

Si la lista tiene los elementos suficientes ocurrirá.

Para minimizar las posibilidades de que esto ocurra hazlo con un bucle. Por ejemplo, de una manera similar a como lo hace la función `Buscar`.

Comment: Buenas noches, quería comentar que intenté implementar el método Buscar que ofreciste, pero no me retornaba falso y se debía al doble igual ("=="), luego intenté colocarlo con solo un igual ("=") y finalmente me retornó falso. Al colocar solo un igual no es suficiente para comparar resultados?(En este caso, la variable ingresada con la que se almacena en la lista).

Comment: El operador `=` es de asignación. Lo que se evalúa como booleano es la variable que precede el `=` por una conversión como la que mencioné. En cambio `==` compara los 2 operandos y evalúa `true` si son iguales. En la mayoría de lenguajes la diferencia es la misma, solo que no existe conversión implícita a `bool` o equivalente.

Comment: Puedes ver que al ejecutar el código con `=` obtienes verdadero por la conversión implícita a `bool` y que un elemento fue reemplazado [aquí](https://ideone.com/ug22ZJ).